# afterFind not working with recursive level 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Issue with `afterFind()`.

**Current code :**

```
 <?php
    public function afterFind($results, $primary = false)
    {
            foreach ($results as $key => $val)
            {
                if (isset($val['User']['country_code']) && isset($val['User']['mobile']))
                {
                    $results[$key]['User']['mobile'] = trim($val['User']['country_code']).trim($val['User']['mobile']);
                }
            }
            return $results;
    }
?>
```

It's working with `$this->User->find()`, but not working with other models.
I have 3 models. `Room`, `Place` and `User`.

```
<?php
    $this->Place->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('User')));
    $this->Room->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Place')));
?>
```

When I try to find `Room` data :

```
<?php
$data = $this->Room->find('first');
array(
    [Room] => array()
    [Place] => array(
        [User] => array(
            [mobile] => /* here after find not working it should content country code + mobile */
        )
    )
)
?>
```

Comment: Don't use recursive anything.  Set it to -1 in your AppModel, and then use Containable Behavior when you want additional associated data.

Answer (score 0):

That might be problem with $reset while binding flyby. http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/source-class-Model.html#868-910

Please set $reset to false.

$this->Model->bindModel(array(...),false);